# Does my Android phone uses battery or outlet power to operate while being charged?

Tags: battery, charging

I am curious about knowing which power source does my android uses up, while it is being charged while switched on..

I know i can test it by keeping it in charging and pulling the battery.. but i am unsure if its safe enough..

Anyone having any ideas??

If it uses outlet/USB power for operation,then i can be assured of keeping it plugged in and use wifi tethering for net surfing for long periods.. without thinking of any battery damage due to prolonged charging..am i right on this?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, my phone (HTC Desire) seems to use battery while being charged... or at least a combination of both. Reason is, while plugged in, if I am doing something intensive - eg playing games, I notice that either the battery % hasn't really increased or has actually decreased!

Also, not sure which phone you are using, so the behaviour maybe different to the Desire, but I'm guessing it uses a lithium-ion battery - here is some good info on "the best way to use Li-ion batteries" http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2011/02/ask-ars-what-is-the-best-way-to-use-an-li-ion-battery.ars

Basically:

- They don't have memory
- Don't worry about overcharging
- Don't completely deplete the battery - lowest ~20%
- Use your battery - you need to 'exercise' the battery
- Try to keep the battery cool

Comment: The Nexus 9 actually loses battery while playing games while charging